# Can't center the image inside of a full-screen overlay modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, overlay

I'm working on my first personal project with basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, and Vanilla Javascript and I'm trying to enlarge a picture on the page by placing it into a modal with the fullscreen overlay background.

I managed to get it bigger and back to the original size again at a click, but I can't  get it centered within the modal. Sometimes it's touching top and bottom with a distorted height, other times both the image and the modal turn out to be too small, and sometimes it's in the left or any other corner of the screen.

I'd like it to be around 70% or 80% of the user screen and be centered both vertically and horizontally, including on the mobile.

The best I could manage is to get it to be the right size that doesn't get it distorted, but it sticks to the left upper corner on desktop and is a bit higher than the center on the mobile. The code is provided below.

HTML

```
<main role="main">    
    <h1 class="h1-mapas">MAPAS DE SUBTE</h1>
    <div class="main-div">
      <div id="img-div" class="img-div">
        <img id="mapa-img" class="mapa-img" src="/images/mapa-subte.jpg" alt="Mapa de subte con todas las líneas y paradas">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="theModal" class="modal">
      <img class="modal-img" id="modalImg">
    </div>
  </main>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

JS

```
const modal = document.getElementById("theModal")
const img = document.getElementById("mapa-img")
const modalImage = document.getElementById("modalImg")

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block"
  modalImage.src = this.src
}

modal.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none"
}
```

I also tried adding and/or removing these in the .modal in CSS as well as changing the modal display to flex in JS and justifying the image centrally in CSS (it gets distorted by height then), but never managed to get it right.

```
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Thanks a lot for your help, everyone!

Comment: using width or height to make the container take fullscreen will likely give you issues. You have the option to use `vh` and `vw` units, but that does have some implications across certain browsers. The most reliable way I've found is to use `inset: 0`, `top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;`, or set using js to determine the screensize on load/resize events.

Comment: The container (.modal overlay) is full-screen, the image inside of it is the problem. I tried to get rid of weight/height and do inset-top-right-left-bottom 0 on either .modal or .modal-img like you advised, but it doesn't work.

When I did it on the .modal, nothing happened and it continued to stay in the upper left corner. When I do it on the image, it just goes huge and not centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `display: grid` for the modal and `place-itmes: center` as part of the CSS.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("theModal")
const img = document.getElementById("mapa-img")
const modalImage = document.getElementById("modalImg")

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "grid" /* Changed */
  modalImage.src = this.src
}

modal.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
#mapa-img {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center; /* Added */
}

.modal-img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<main role="main">
  <h1 class="h1-mapas">MAPAS DE SUBTE</h1>
  <div class="main-div">
    <div id="img-div" class="img-div">
      <img id="mapa-img" class="mapa-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Mapa de subte con todas las líneas y paradas">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="theModal" class="modal">
    <img class="modal-img" id="modalImg">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! Should I always use grid for modals like this then?

Comment: @buckwhitzer That's what I would recommend.